# Array of Function Pointers error: Initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to create a function pointer array that holds an array of pointers to functions. But I keep getting the initialization from incompatible pointer type error at the `fun_ptr fun_ptr_arr[3] = {fun1, fun2, fun3};` initializer.

I tried `typedef void (*fun_ptr) (myStruct**,char**);` but the error still persists and I'm not sure what went wrong.

```
struct myStruct
{
    char *value;
    struct myStruct *next;
}
typedef void (*fun_ptr) (myStruct**,char*[]);

void fun1 (myStruct **theStruct, const char **arguments) {};
void fun2 (myStruct **theStruct, const char **arguments) {};
void fun3 (myStruct **theStruct, const char **arguments) {};

void main()
{
    fun_ptr fun_ptr_arr[3] = {fun1, fun2, fun3};
}
```

And my error, for each of the functions

```
test.c:285:69: note: (near initialization for ‘fun_ptr_arr[0]’)
test.c:285:69: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  fun_ptr fun_ptr_arr[3] = {fun1, fun2, fun3};
                            ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: When asking about build errors, always remember to include the *full* and *complete* error output, verbatim, in the question body.

Comment: You need to post the first error message, not the last one. Only the first error message is correct, the rest are usually nonsense.

Comment: You're missing `myStruct;` at the end of your struct definition. Other than that, there are no compilation errors!!!

Comment: You need to copy-and-paste the actual code you're compiling into the question. We can't tell which errors are in your actual code, and which you introduced when you re-typed (and possibly summarized) it. In the question, you're missing a semicolon after the struct definition (5th line), and you refer to the type `struct myStruct` as just `myStruct` (legal in C++, illegal in C). When I fix those errors, I get no errors, but several warnings, mostly about unused parameters.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of each function definition is a syntax error, though many compilers will ignore it by default. `void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @goodvibration: Adding `myStruct` at the end of the struct definition would define an object, not a type name. Either use `typedef` or (preferably IMHO) refer to the type by its correct name, `struct myStruct`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: What do you mean `an object, not a type`? This is C, remember (and in fact, even in C++, the term `object` refers to design methodology, and is not any part of the language standard). But you're right that I forgot to mention - `typedef` at the beginning.

Comment: You should get an error on the line `typedef void (*fun_ptr) (myStruct**,const char*[]);` because `myStruct` is not defined. Please make sure you posted the exact code you are compiling, it might also help to show how you are invoking the compiler

Comment: @goodvibration The term "object" refers to a region of storage (with some nuances), in the C standard and the C++ standard.

Comment: @goodvibration: As M.M says, an "object" in C is by definition a "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values". [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 3.15. The C++ definition is similar (and has nothing to do with OOP)..

Comment: You edited the code in your question to correct the problem pointed out in Marshall Clow's answer. Please don't do that. It invalidates the answer and makes your question useless to future readers. (I've edited it back.)

Comment: My code above isn't my exact code. Mine included the const. My issue earlier was not that const, and it was a missing asterisk in another portion of the code. However I will leave it as such. My apologies as I now understand that not providing the actual code makes it difficult for others to provide accurate answers. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prototype is `typedef void (*fun_ptr) (myStruct**,char*[]);`

Your functions are: `void fun1 (myStruct **, const char **)`

Note the extra `const`

Those are different types, and so, the compiler complains.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that out in my original qns. Have update it to reflect the const

Comment: if I copy your code and add a missing semi-colon, and change the return type of `main` to be `int`, it complies w/o any warnings or errors for me, even using `-Wpedantic -Wall`

Comment: Ah. I realised what I missed out. Thanks!